# How to find the minimum value of the expression?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be three nonegative real numbers and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5.$ Find the minimum of the expression
$$E=\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2) + \dfrac{96}{x + y + z + 1}.$$
What should I do find the minimum of this expression?

Comment: I am assuming the tag should really be "multivariable-calculus".  You want to start by finding the partial derivatives of $E$ with respect to each of the three variables (that's less awful than it sounds) and set those equal to zero.  Find the values of $x, y, $ and $z$ for which all of those equations are simultaneously true.  The set of all possible ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ are your critical points for the function.  You then need to find what _sorts_ of critical points they are...

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is a scalar function from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and you have to find its maximum over the surface $S=\{(x,y,z)x^2+y^2+z^2=5\}.$ Now use Lagrange multiplier method to solve $\nabla E=\lambda \nabla S$  and find the critical points. Put there value in E to find the maximum.

Comment: oopss........it seems Reckless has already posted it..........

Comment: Well, not quite:  I was proposing the approach without using Lagrange, since I wasn't assuming the OP was familiar with it.  The "multipliers" would make things a lot easier...

Comment: It turns out that the Lagrange-multiplier is not really all that helpful here, as it produces a rather difficult algebraic problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

this is a complex question, the real max of E is when $x=\sqrt{5}$, the min of E is when $x=1.85262,y=z=1.254468$, $ E_{min}=23.76$, since the $E$ is symmetry for $x,y,z$ ,so the max and min will be obtain when $ y=z $(WLOG), so E will become a $f(x)$,then $f'(x)=0$, will have 3 real roots. one is $x=y=z$, another is $x=1.19782$.but when we have$f'(x)$, we assume $x^2 \not= 5$ ,but it is a max point.

Answer (score 1):

The restriction on the variable values is necessary, as we see from a geometrical interpretation of the problem. The second term in the function $ \ E \ $ is undefined on the plane $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1 \ = \ 0 \ $ , which intersects the sphere $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 5 \ $ :

[image]

So there is a circle of intersection on which the term $ \ \frac{96}{x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1} \ $ is undefined.  As we approach this circle from points on the surface where the sum $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1 \ $ is positive, the function $ \ E \ $ will tend to positive infinity, and will tend to negative infinity as we approach the circle from the other side of the plane.  The function $ \ E \ $ then has no global maximum or minimum.

Since no part of this circle enters the first octant, however, $ \ E \ $ is positive and remains finite there, so we can investigate local minima in that portion of the spherical surface.  The function is unaffected by "exchanges" of the variables, so we can expect that critical points may be found in places where the function has symmetry.

This is borne out by finding the loci of points where the first partial derivatives of the function equal zero:

$$ E_x \ = \ xy^2 \ + \ xz^2 \ - \ \frac{96}{(x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1)^2} \ = \ 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ (y^2 \ + \ z^2) \ = \ \frac{96}{(x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1)^2} \ \ , $$

and similarly for $ \ E_y \ $ and $ \ E_z \ $  .  The right-hand sides of these equations are all identical; if we apply the "spherical surface constraint", we can write

$$ x \ (5 \ - \ x^2) \ = \ y \ (5 \ - \ y^2) \ = \ z \ (5 \ - \ z^2) \ \ . $$

(Applying Lagrange multipliers does not appear to be as helpful, as the method  also produces a symmetric equation of this sort, but one which is much more difficult to resolve.)

If we graph a single pair of terms, $ x \ (5 \ - \ x^2) \ = \ y \ (5 \ - \ y^2) \ $ , from this equation, we observe this:

[image]

*the circle in blue is the "equator" of our sphere*

Our expectation is confirmed, at least in the $ \ xy-$ plane, that the critical points are found either on the line $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ or on the coordinate axes.  When we view this in three dimensions, however, the equation $ x \ (5 \ - \ x^2) \ = \ y \ (5 \ - \ y^2) \ $ describes a "cylinder", and the intersection with the spherical surface resembles an ellipse with a "meridian line" running through it:

[image]

The simplest points to examine are those for which $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ $ and either $ \ x \ $ or $ \ y \ $ are also zero.  For $ \ y \ = \ 0 \ $ , we have $ \ x^2 \ = \ 5 \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \sqrt{5} \ $ ; so at $ \ ( \ \sqrt{5}, \ 0, \ 0 \ ) $ and $ \ ( \ 0, \ \sqrt{5}, \ 0 \ ) $ , we find $ \ E \ = \ \frac{96}{1 \ + \ \sqrt{5}} \ \approx \ 29.67 \ $ , which **chenbai** identifies as a local maximum.

The next simplest place to check on the "equator" is where $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , at $ \ \left( \ \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}, \ \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}, \ 0 \ \right) $ , for which

$$ E \ = \ \frac{1}{2}  \left(  \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \right)^4 \ + \ \dfrac{96}{ 1 \ + \ 2 \left(  \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \right) } \ = \ \frac{25}{8}   \ + \ \dfrac{96}{ 1 \ + \   \sqrt{10}  }  \ \approx \ 26.19 \ \ . $$

We should also look at the "meridian line" , $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , with $ \ z \ = \ \sqrt{5 \ - \ 2x^2} \ $ , requiring us to examine

$$ \dfrac{1}{2}( \ x^4 \ + \ 2x^2 \ [5 \ - \ 2x^2] \ ) \ + \ \dfrac{96}{1 \ + \ 2x \ + \ \sqrt{5 \ - \ 2x^2} } \ \ . $$

Perhaps a bit surprisingly, the minimum lies approximately at $ \ ( 0.886, \ 0.886, \ 1.852) \ $ , at which $ \ E \ \approx \ 23.76 \ $ ; this point is on the meridian line, but *inside* the wall of the elliptic cylinder depicted in the above diagram.  (I used a graph to locate this, since differentiation produces a rather daunting algebra problem to solve.  The graph also confirms the values of $ \ E \ $ computed at the locations mentioned above, with $ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ E \ \approx \ 29.67 $ at the "north pole" of the sphere.)

If we put together all three pairs of equations in $ x \ (5 \ - \ x^2) \ = \ y \ (5 \ - \ y^2) \ = \ z \ (5 \ - \ z^2) \ $ , we have three mutually orthogonal "cylinders", which look like this:

[image]

So an additional point we ought to check is on the line $ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ z \ $ (as the "exchange symmetry" of the function initially suggested), that being
$ \ \left( \ \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}, \ \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}, \ \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \ \right) $ , for which we obtain

$$ E \ = \ \frac{1}{2}   \cdot 3 \ \left(  \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \right)^4 \ + \ \dfrac{96}{ 1 \ + \ 3 \left(  \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \right) } \ = \ \frac{25}{6}   \ + \ \dfrac{96}{ 1 \ + \   \sqrt{15}  }   \ \approx \ 23.867 \ \ . $$

On examining the aforementioned graph for $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , this turns out to be an *extremely* shallow *maximum*.

The value of the function here is actually slightly *larger* than it is at the point $ \ ( 0.886, \ 0.886, \ 1.852) \ $ .  Hence, there appear to be three minima of $ \ E \ $ , since the function is unchanged by "cyclic rotation" of its variables.  The minimum value of about $ \ 23.76 \ $ occurs at $ \ ( 0.886, \ 0.886, \ 1.852) \ \ , \  \ ( 0.886, \ 1.852, \ 0.886) \ \ $ , and $ \ \ ( 1.852, \ 0.886, \ 0.886) \ $ .

[There are also very shallow local minima for points where two of the coordinates have the value $ \ 1.335 \ $ and $ \ E \ \approx \ 23.867 \ $; otherwise, I essentially confirm **chenbai**'s conclusions.]