# Find maximum of $P$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

Let $$P = \frac{{{x^2}}}{{{x^2} + yz + x + 1}} + \frac{{y + z}}{{x + y + z + 1}} - \frac{{1 + yz}}{9}.$$ 
Find maximum of $P$  where $x, y,z$ are nonnegative real numbers such that ${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 2$.

I guess $\max P=\dfrac{5}{9}$ when $x=y=1, z=0$. But I can not prove.

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange multipliers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: I've tried but it implies a system of equations that I couldn't solve.

Comment: @emcor: $x,y,z$ are nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: You can substitute $x^2=2-y^2-z^2$, and then extend the fractions by the denominators to see what cancels..

Comment: I have tried but no progress.

Comment: $(1,0,1)$ would also be a maximum with $P=5/9$

Comment: Can you give the term you get after substitution and extending by denominators?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is a hint.

Comment: I think you can set $z=y$ for $z,y\neq0$ because the equation is symmetric with regard to them.

Comment: For $z=y$ I get a lower [maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%2B%282z%29%2F%28x%2B2z%2B1%29-%281%2Bz%5E2%29%2F9+on+x%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D2%2C+x%3E%3D0%2C+z%3E%3D0), so $(1,0,1)$ should be the [global maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2Byz%2Bx%2B1%29%2B%28y%2Bz%29%2F%28x%2By%2Bz%2B1%29-%281%2Byz%29%2F9+on+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D2%2C+x%3E0%2C+y%3E0%2C+z%3E0).

Comment: Lagrange multipliers have a somewhat limited utility; the inequality technique used in the answer below is probably the most effective approach to take.  Even for a function with more symmetry than this one, "Lagrange" doesn't help much -- see this problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374958/how-to-find-the-minimum-value-of-the-expression?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1.** Prove that
$$
x^2+yz+x+1\geq x(x+y+z+1)
$$
by using the expansion of $(x-y-z)^2\geq 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$.

**Step 2.** Observe that
$$
x+y+z\leq\sqrt{2(x^2+(y+z)^2)}=2\sqrt{1+yz}
$$
**Step 3.** By Step 1, we have
$$
P\leq\frac{x^2}{x(x+y+z+1)}+\frac{y+z}{x+y+z+1}-\frac{1+yz}{9}=1-Q
$$
with 
$$
Q=\frac{1}{x+y+z+1}+\frac{1+yz}{9}.
$$
By step 2 we have
$$
Q\geq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+yz}+1}+\frac{1+yz}{9}.
$$
Let $t=\sqrt{1+yz}\geq 1$ and
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{2t+1}+\frac{t^2}{9}
$$
We can find
$$
\min_{t\geq 0}f(t)=f(0)=\frac{4}{9}
$$
and so  $\max P=\frac{5}{9}$ at $x=y=1, z=0$.

Comment: nice!a minor typo,last 2nd line:"0" should be "1".

Answer (score 0):

This function is complicated and asymmetrical enough that it doesn't yield much to the tools generally taught in multivariable calculus.  As I commented above, the inequality approach shown by **impartialmale** is probably the most direct approach to determining the maximum value of $ \ P(x, \ y, \ z) \ $ .

Here's what can be extracted for the behavior of the function in the first octant by straightforward analysis.  The function is undefined on the surfaces $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ + \ 1 \ = 0 \ $ and $ \ x^2 \ + \ yz \ + \ x \ + \ 1 \ = \ 0 \ $ , but neither of these intersects the spherical constraint surface $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 2 \ $ in the first octant; so there is no problem of the function lacking global extrema there.  The first partial derivatives are

$$ P_x \ = \ -\frac{2x + yz + 2}{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ - \ \frac{y + z}{(x + y + z + 1)^2} \ \ ;  $$

$$ P_y \ = \ -\frac{z + x^2 + x + 1}{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ - \ \frac{x}{(x + y + z + 1)^2} \ - \ \frac{z}{9} \ \ ;  $$

$$ P_z \ = \ -\frac{y + x^2 + x + 1}{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ - \ \frac{x}{(x + y + z + 1)^2} \ - \ \frac{y}{9} \ \ . $$

Setting $ \ P_x \ = \ 0 \ $ doesn't really give us much to work with, as you already found.  We can get a *bit* further by setting the other two partial derivatives equal to zero:

$$ -\frac{z + x^2 + x + 1}{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ = \ \frac{x}{(x + y + z + 1)^2} \ + \ \frac{z}{9} \ \ $$
$$ -\frac{y + x^2 + x + 1}{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ = \ \frac{x}{(x + y + z + 1)^2} \ + \ \frac{y}{9} \ \ ; $$

subtracting the second equation from the first produces

$$ \frac{y - z }{(x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2}  \ = \  \frac{z - y}{9} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (x^2 + yz + x + 1)^2 \ = \ -9 \ \ ,   $$

for $ \ y \ \ne \ z \ $ . So we learn very little about critical points of $ \ P \ $ over the spherical surface this way, other than that there won't be any to find on the constraint surface that are not on the plane $ \ y \ = \ z \ $ ; everything else of interest turns up on the "edges". Likewise, the Lagrange-multiplier method is rather unavailing here.

Because the function is unchanged by the "exchange" of $ \ y \ $ and $ \ z \ $ , a good place to examine will be the intersection of the constraint surface with the plane $ \ y \ = \ z \ $ .  We will also want to inspect the quarter-circles where the spherical surface intersects each of the coordinate planes.  The function reduces to

$$ P(x, \ y, \ 0) \ = \ P(x, \ 0, \ z) \ = \ \frac{x^2}{x^2 + x + 1} \ + \ \frac{\sqrt{2 - x^2}}{x + 1 + \sqrt{2 - x^2}} \ - \ \frac{1}{9} \ \ , $$

$$ P(0, \ y, \ z) \ = \ \frac{z + \sqrt{2 - z^2}}{1 + z + \sqrt{2 - z^2}} \ - \ \frac{1 + z \sqrt{2 - z^2}}{9} \ \ , $$

$$ P(x, \ z, \ z) \ = \ \frac{x^2}{\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x + 2} \ + \ \frac{2 \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{2}}}{{x + 1 + 2 \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{2}}}} \ - \ \frac{(2 - \frac{x^2}{2})}{9} \ \ . $$

I didn't attempt to differentiate these to search for their respective critical points, since it looked like further "algebraic messes" would result.  Inspecting graphs of the first and third functions on the interval $ \ 0 \ \le \ x \ \le \ \sqrt{2} \ $ and the second on $ \ 0 \ \le \ z \ \le \ \sqrt{2} \ $ locates the following results for critical points and endpoints:

$ (\sqrt{2}, \ 0, \ 0) \  : \ \ $ **global minimum** $ \ \frac{2}{3 + \sqrt{2}}  -  \frac{1}{9} \ \approx \ 0.342 \ $ ,

$ (0, \ \sqrt{2}, \ 0) \ \ , \ \ (0, \ 0, \ \sqrt{2}) \  : \ \ \approx \ 0.475 \ $ ,

$ (1, \ 1, \ 0) \ \ , \ \ (1, \ 0, \ 1) \  : \ \ $ **global maximum** $ \ \ \frac{5}{9} \ \approx \ 0.556 \ $ ,

$ (0, \ 1, \ 1) \  : \ \  \frac{4}{9}  \ \approx \ 0.444 \ $ ,

$ (\approx 0.150, \ \approx 1.406, \ 0) \ \ , \ \ (\approx 0.150, \ 0, \ \approx 1.406) \  : \ \ $ local minimum $ \ \  \approx \ 0.458 \ $ ,

$ (0, \ \approx 1.413, \ \approx 0.06) \ \ , \ \ (0, \ \approx 0.06,  \ \approx 1.413) \  : \ \ $ local maximum $ \ \  \approx \ 0.475 \ $ ,

$ (\approx 0.235, \ \approx 0.986, \ \approx 0.986) \  : \ \ $ local minimum $ \ \  \approx \ 0.420 \ $ , and

$ (\approx 1.182, \ \approx 0.549, \ \approx 0.549) \  : \ \ $ local maximum $ \ \  \approx \ 0.550 \ $ .

We see from this that the "level surfaces" for $ \ P \ $ would have a rather complicated structure, making it difficult to characterize the extrema in detail with simple analytical techniques.