# An extremal problem using AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $x, y, z$ be nonnegative real numbers and such that
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=2.
$$
Find the maximum value of
$$
P=\frac{x^2}{x^2+yz+x+1}+\frac{y+z}{x+y+z+1}-\frac{1+yz}{9}.
$$
**My attempt.** I guess that $P$ attains its maximum value at $x=y=1, z=0$ and the maximum value is $\frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: where did you get this question from? I don't think AM-GM is involved (though I could be wrong)

Comment: @CalvinLin I got this question from a test in my country.

Comment: Note: This has been [posted before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857148/find-maximum-of-p) though no answers were provided.

Comment: Thank you @CalvinLin. I gave the solution at your provided link.

Comment: Fix $x$. Now setting either $y$ or $z$ to zero maximises the first term. The second term is maximised for terms which maximise $(y+z)$ constrained to a circle, so again, either $y=0$ or $z=0$. Similarly, the last term is also maximised for either $y=0$ or $z=0$.

At the very least, you can now set either $y$ or $z$ as zero (the problem is symmetric under interchange of $y$ and $z$), substitute in the constraint and solve the resulting single-variable problem. Not sure how to use AM-GM.

Comment: @Bhoot The second term is maximized when $y+z$ is maximized, constraint on $y^2 + z^2 = K$, and this happens when $y=z$. The minimum occurs when $yz=0$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Indeed you are correct. I worked through that a bit too quickly. We have that $P$ is symmetric under interchange of $y$ and $z$. Perhaps there is a way of using this to reduce the problem to an optimisation over two variables instead of three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that: $\frac{x^2}{x^2+yz+x+1}\le \frac{x}{x+y+z+1}\Leftrightarrow (y+z-x)^2\ge 0$

So, we have: $P\le\frac{x}{x+y+z+1}+1-\frac{x+1}{x+y+z+1}-\frac{1+yz}{9}$

$\Leftrightarrow P\le 1-(\frac{1}{x+y+z+1}+\frac{1+yz}{9})$

Set: $Q=\frac{1}{x+y+z+1}+\frac{1+yz}{9}$ . We'll find the minimum Q.

Notice that: $x+(y+z)\le \sqrt{2[x^2+(y+z)^2]}=2\sqrt{1+yz}$

$\Rightarrow Q\ge\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+yz}+1}+\frac{1+yz}{9}\longrightarrow \sqrt{1+yz}=t>0\rightarrow Q\ge f(t)=\frac{1}{2t+1}+\frac{t^2}{9}$

We have: $f'(t)=-\frac{2}{(2t+1)^2}-\frac{2t}{9}=0\Leftrightarrow t=1$

$\Rightarrow Q\ge f(t)\ge f(1)=\frac{4}{9}\Rightarrow P\le\frac{5}{9}$